# Getting around lack of 'Contains' in Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

I have the following function (which is hosted in a WCF service, if that matters):

```
    public List<IceVsRepositoryFile> GetRepositoryFilesByRepositoryId(int repId)
    {
        var entity = new IceVSEntities();
        var files = from p in entity.Files where p.RepositoryId == repId select p.FileId;
        List<long> iList = files.ToList();
        var repFiles = from p in entity.RepositoryFiles where iList.Contains(p.FileId) select p;

        if (!repFiles.Any())
            return null;

        var retFiles = repFiles.ToList().Select(z => new IceVsRepositoryFile
            {
                FileId = (int)z.FileId,
                RollbackFileId = (int)z.RollbackFileId,
                UserId = (int)z.UserId,
                FileContents = z.FileContents,
                ChangeDescription = z.ChangeDescription
            }).ToList();

        return retFiles;
    }
```

When I run this function I am getting the following an error that says "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int64)' method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I understand why I am getting the error message. My question is, how can I rewrite my query to make this work as expected? My backend database, if it matters, if SqlLite 3. I am using .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contains you used is for `List`, it's not in IEnumerable so it can't be converted to corresponding sql query. Instead you can use `Any`, ... like:

```
iList.Any(x=>x == p.FileId) (or use related property)
```

Also instead of doing:

```
List<long> iList = files.ToList();
```

use `files.Any...` in your query to prevent from too many fetching from DB. Actually use IEnumerable functions instead of `List` functions.

Comment: I think the problem is actually that the database does not have iList or files, so it cannot filter based on them.  I don't think that changing the call to 'Any' will help.  If RepositoryFiles is small enough that it isn't a problem to load into memory, I would call ToList() on it instead.  Another option is to combine the two queries into one, but that would probably repeat the first query for each item in ReposityryFiles.  ToList() on the first query also stops this query from hitting the database multiple times.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin, My answer is absolutely correct and it doesn't deserve for downvote, downvote is for wrong answers. Also all of your guesses are wrong. Because of deferred execution, execution of code will postpone (in the way that I wrote), but your suggestion seems to be correct not necessary better than mind.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the problem with translating the LINQ into SQL, and you provide some poor advice without qualification or explanation.  .ToList() is there for a reason, and will help in this situation.  It shouldn't be mindlessly avoided.  .Any() is good to know about, but is pointless here. I, however, didn't downvote you.  It was borderline though.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri -- Trying this threw up a different error for me: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String and Guid) are supported in this context. The ID is an Int64. Could thise be causing the problem?

Comment: @icemanind, would you show me your updated query? also what is int64? as I can see you used int32 for `repId`.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - Yeah, when I generated the entities using Entity Framework, EF mapped my primary keys to Int64. In reality, Int32 would work just fine

Answer (score 1):

I believe a join can do this:

```
public List<IceVsRepositoryFile> GetRepositoryFilesByRepositoryId(int repId)
{
  var entity = new IceVSEntities();    

  var repFiles = from file in entity.Files where file.RepositoryId == repId join repFile in entity.RepositoryFiles on repFile.FileId equals file.FileId select repFile;

  var retFiles = // as before

  return retFiles;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a relationship between Files and RepositoryFiles?  If so, it would be easier to do something like this:

```
var repFiles = from p in entity.RepositoryFiles where p.File.RepositoryId == repId select p;
```

This will avoid the problems with being unable to translate the query to SQL.

Comment: I do not have a relationship. Though that would be an easy solve